# How can Pascal have conditions when it doesn't have boolean type?

Tags: grammar, pascal, ebnf

Based on formal [Pascal EBNF definition](http://www.pascal-central.com/docs/iso7185.pdf) (pg69-75), I saw that Pascal only supports 3 primitive types: Integer, Real and String.

In C, any values which are different from `0` can be interpreted as a `true` literal. Pascal doesn't work like C. How can Pascal deal with conditional expressions when it doesn't have Boolean type?

Comment: C managed perfectly well without a boolean type, and I still never use the boolean type that was intoduced.

Comment: No, in C, conditional expressions representing 'true' equate to `1`. I think we can safely remove that tag. Also, a quick search indicates to me that Pascal does support booleans. Are you sure that definition is in any way authoritative?

Comment: I do recall encountering one implementation of what claimed to be Pascal which did not have a predefined boolean type; everything seemed to work acceptably if one defined `TYPE BOOLEAN = (FALSE, TRUE);`

Comment: [See pascal at ISO](https://www.iso.org/standard/13802.html)

Comment: This is about Pascal only. Mentioning C does not qualify for the C tag. But as you mention how conditions are evaluated to a boolean value, why do you think this could not be the same in Pascal? (IIRC, the UCSD-Pascal and Turbo-Pascal I used decades ago did have a BOOLEAN type, but the memory is faint). Your question is not clear. You just cite some external site, without reference how this is complete or mandatory for all Pascal implementations. That's the same as if we ask about some home-made C compiler lacking a feature.

Comment: @Olaf I referenced to the ISO standard page. The old external reference copied from this standard.

Comment: @MiP: I certainly will not dig throught tens of pages of a PDF which does not even have a TOC. You have to learn how to read languages specifications. As stated in the anser, the syntax and grammar specification does not specify a language completely.

Comment: In other words: wrong question. It has a Boolean type. That may not show *explicitly* in the EBNF, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Olaf: a TOC should indeed be included. Also note that hardly anyone uses ISO Pascal these days. There are far more popular and useful dialects, like Delphi or FreePascal (the latter is actually a compiler for several similar dialects).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis "hardly anyone uses ISO Pascal these days" - Did anyone ever?? I only remember UCSD-p Pascal on Apple-II and others, later Turbo Pascal  Both before ISO-Pascal and much more useful than the original Wirth Pascal (although UCSD-p Pascal was  quite close).

Comment: @Olaf: I did, but that was in 1983+, on my Beeb (Acorn BBC computer). Later I got hooked on Turbo Pascal and Delphi.

Comment: @RudyVelthuisConsidering Pascal was first standardised 1989, I have doubts.

Comment: @Olaf: According to the 1990 document, NSI/IEEE770X3.97-1983 was the first. "International Standard 7185 (incorporating BS6192 by reference) was approved by ISO on December 1, 1983."

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Then Wikipedia is wrong. I have to confess I just did a short check there and digged not deeper. At that time I was busy enough learning programming, etc. and understanding what I actually did. I happily moved to Modula-2 some years later (C was near unusable that time - at least for someone used to strong typing and a clean library system.

Comment: @Olaf: Wikipedia says: "In 1983, the language was standardized, in the international standard IEC/ISO 7185". Unless you just changed that, it was not wrong. <g> FWIW, my first programming language was ZX80 BASIC. Then BBC BASIC (which had procedures and functions and local variables, and repeat until, etc.), 6502 assembler, BCPL and Acorn ISO Pascal, then Turbo Pascal on the PC.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Not the German version https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(Programmiersprache)#Standards But yes, I really should get used to reading the English versions; they are often more complete anyway

Comment: @Olaf: Ah, OK, that one is wrong. It only mentions the 1990 standard. But both Delphi and FreePascal are mostly (not entirely) compatible to the standard.

Comment: The EBNF you are looking at is not a true grammar for the Pascal programming language. It is notation which explains only parts of the Pascal programming language. The language of syntactically correct Pascal programs is not context-free and there is no EBNF grammar for it.

Comment: A part that the linked document seems to mention booleans, for what I recall, a boolean type is not necessary to be a Turing-machine-compatible language. Right?

Comment: @Patrick87: There are several EBNF grammars for Pascal, and also for dialects like Delphi and FreePascal.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It's been a while since I used Python, but if you declare variables before you use them then the language cannot be context-free, and what I take EBNF to mean doesn't apply. You can represent some rules but not all. I've heard a distinction made between syntax and semantics here but I have always felt that's hand waving.

Comment: @Patrick87: This is about Pascal, not Python.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Typo - still applies to Pascal.

Comment: @Patrick87: OK, these syntaxes are probably WSN (Wirth syntax notation). Wirth also developed EBNF, IIRC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Pascal standard clearly defines the syntax and semantics of a Boolean-type.

Quoting from the document you link to:

> #### 6.4.2.2 Required simple-types
>
> The following types shall exist:
>
> …
>
> c. *Boolean-type*. The required type-identifier **Boolean** shall denote the Boolean-type. The Boolean-type shall be an ordinal-type. The values shall be the enumeration of truth values denoted by the required constant-identifiers **false** and **true**, such that **false** is the predecessor of **true**.
> *(page 16)*

The values **true** and **false**  correspond to the EBNF production:

```
constant = [ sign ] (constant-identifier | number) | string
```

which can produce:

```
constant = constant-identifier
```

(since `[ sign ]` is optional)

A `constant-identifier` is just an `identifier`.

Also:

> #### 6.7.2.3 Boolean operators
>
> …
>
> ```
>  Boolean-expression = expression .
> ```
>
> A Boolean-expression shall be an expression that denotes a value of Boolean-type.
> *(page 49)*

Table 6 (on the following page) defines the operand and result types of the comparison operators (`==`, `<=`, `>=`, `<>`, `<`, `>` and `in`). In all cases, the result type is "Boolean-type".

Finally:

> #### 6.8.3.4 If-statements
>
> If the Boolean-expression of the if-statement yields the value **true**, the statement of the if-statement shall be executed. If the Boolean-expression yields the value **false**, the statement of the if-statement shall not be executed, and the statement of the else-part, if any, shall be executed.
> *(page 54)*

Answer (score 4):

The EBNF does not describe the type system, it describes the syntax, and only the syntax.  Note, however, that if you declare a variable it has a type:

```
variable-declaration =
identifier-list ":" type .
```

And a type is defined as:

```
type =
simple-type | structured-type | pointer-type | type-identifier .
```

And `type-identifier` is just `identifier` can be `boolean`, but the EBNF won't tell you that. You have to look at the rest of the standard. ISO 7185 defines a dialect of Pascal, and the relevant section is 6.4.2.2:

> The values shall be the enumeration of truth values denoted by the required constant-identifiers `false` and `true`...

In Pascal, you could end up with code like this:

```
program BooleanDemo;
var
    myBool : boolean;
    n : integer;
begin
    n := 5;
    myBool := n > 4;
    if myBool then
        writeln('myBool is true')
    else
        writeln('myBool is false')
end.
```

Try running this code yourself, and you will see that there is in fact a boolean type, and it works exactly as you'd expect.

Comment: I think it's not the case. Because based on the EBNF, I cannot declare `true`, `false`, or logical negation like `not true`, `not false`: `constant = [ sign ] (constant-identifier | number) | string`.

Comment: @MiP: Again, the real problem here is that you are only looking at the EBNF. Note that `true` and `false` both fall under `constant-identifier`, but the EBNF won't tell you that. It turns out that you actually have to read the standard, and skimming the EBNF (which, again, *only* describes the syntax and nothing else) will give you an incomplete understanding of the language. Refer to ISO 7185 section 6.4.2.2 for a description of the boolean type.

Comment: Thanks for your references. Sadly, based on the syntaxes alone, I cannot write logical negations `not` for constants. I don't know why they supported `sign` negation and identity operators for number, but not for boolean.

Comment: @MiP: This is also incorrect, you can in fact use logical negation `not` in Pascal. This is specified in ISO 7185 section 6.7, and it appears in the EBNF, in the body of the text, and in numerous examples.

Comment: @MiP: I'm curious... have you ever actually used Pascal, or looked at Pascal code? Or are you trying to figure out Pascal just by looking at the EBNF? Because it seems like you are trying to figure things out just by looking at the EBNF. Just looking at the EBNF by itself will lead to a terribly incomplete understanding of the language.

Comment: I wrote that I couldn't use `not` in constant declarations, because I saw that `not` only appeared in expressions (section 6.7). I'm learning to start writing a simple parser for a subset of ISO Pascal, so I need to look at EBNF carefully.

Comment: @MiP: Okay, you actually didn't mention that you were talking about constant declarations specifically.

Comment: @MiP: `not` isn't allowed in constant expressions because it is unnecessary. Or better said, unary negation is allowed because there is no alternative. Suppose you wanted a case clause or a range with a negative number: you could not write that without negative constants. But `not` does not expand the range of boolean constants; `not true` is `false` and `not false` is `true`. C (perhaps more sensibly) allows a constant expression to be any well-defined arithmetic expression with only constant literals as operands, but standard Pascal was not prepared to go that far.

Comment: @rici I think it's useful to have `not` in constant declarations because it can be used to negate other constant identifiers for clearer code in specific cases though.

Comment: @mip: i think it's useful to allow, for example, `N+1` in constant declarations, but that was not the decision taken by the framers of standard Pascal 25 years ago, and it is far too late to complain about it.